# Return either blank or numeric value

Tags: sql-server-2012, null

I have looked and looked and can not find an answer anywhere so I am hoping you guys can help me. I am pulling data from multiple tables using a left join. Some info is not in the right table so it pulls across as NULL. The end user is requesting that all NULL values show as blank. I can easily do this for columns with string datatypes but I have not been able to figure out a way to do this for columns with numeric, int, money, or float datatypes.

See screenshot for simplistic example:
[image: Example]

Using SQL Sever 2012

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want to hear but you might need to convert the numeric columns in your result set to a **string** type (nvarchar, varchar...etc) and then put a **CASE WHEN** structure in your **SELECT** around each one of those columns and check if the value of the field is **NULL** then print '' the blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
select
    NumberNull=case when ISNUMERIC(YourField)=1 then cast(YourField AS varchar(100)) else '' end
```